# Is it necessary to unit test Spring @Autowired setter methods?

Tags: java, spring, junit, autowired, setter

For example, is it necessary to write a `Unit test` for the following Method:

```
private PersonRepository personRepository;

@Autowired
public void setPersonRepository(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }
```

What purpose would the test serve?

Comment: I think it's a good question but I'm pretty sure the linked question covers the situation sufficiently, so I closed as duplicate.

Comment: I do not feel that it is a duplicate as it is specific to spring and autowiring?

Comment: The *answer* is covered there even if the question is slightly different. If it's not then you need to explain why not and the question can be reopened (e.g. by me). I have enough expertise in Java and unit testing to bet those are the answers you are looking for and they apply to this situation with Spring.

Comment: If you want to test if your spring config is working it is probably an integration test, and not a unit test. And if you write an integration test, you are not primarily testing the method but if the `PersonRepository` can be autowired.